# Find if there is more than one path between two vertices such that no vertices are used more than once

Tags: graphs

So I have an undirected graph G(V, E). We may assume there is always at least one path between any two vertices. I want to efficiently check if there are at least 2 different paths between *x* and *y* that have no vertices in common. (I'm pretty sure that) Equivalent problem would be to find if all paths between *x* and *y* go through a vertex (I don't need to know which one). My first idea was to just run a BFS, creating a list of paths and checking if all of the paths have a common vertex, however, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about how to find a pair of vertex-disjoint paths from $x$ to $y$.  You can use [Suurballe's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm) to solve this.  See the "variations" part of that page for how to adapt it to find vertex-disjoint paths.  Suurballe's algorithm works with directed graphs.  You can convert an undirected graph to a directed graph by replacing each undirected edge $(u,v)$ with two directed edges $u \to v$, $v \to u$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Thanks to your comment, I was able to find [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/345601&ved=2ahUKEwip3cLpnfz8AhWggv0HHRFgDiEQFnoECDEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0yfGHRMT1MVFSvsFTWH3ui) which matches more closely what I need in a better runtime - O(|E|)